# imap: .y not found

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

This is really weird.

```
foo <- list(a=2, b=3)
imap(foo, ~ print(.y))
```

This works:

```
[1] "a"
[1] "b"
$a
[1] "a"

$b
[1] "b"
```

This also works:

```
imap(foo, ~ paste("ID", .y))
```

result:

```
$a
[1] "ID a"

$b
[1] "ID b"
```

But this doesn't:

```
imap(foo, ~ bar <- .y)
```

Result:

```
Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object '.y' not found
```

What the heck? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order of operation. `~` has precedence over `<-`. Use parentheses.

```
imap(foo, ~ (bar <- .y))
```

Comment: Thanks! That was precisely the problem.